# django multi form and file field

Tags: django

I am currently using several differences forms on a single view. I am able to fill my forms but when I submit one of them, it seems that my form is invalid. I displayed the request.POST (it contains all my information) and my form (it contains my information except files parts.)

Could you explain me how to correct it?
Could it be linked to my models?

(I am using bootstrap 3 through django)

my view :

```
def view_addfiles(request):
try:
    print(request.POST)
except:
    {}
if request.method == 'POST' and 'search' in request.POST:
    print("recherche")
    recherche=searchbar(request.POST, prefix='search')
    if recherche.is_valid():
        print("recherche")
else : 
    recherche=searchbar(prefix='search')

if request.method == 'POST' and 'film' in request.POST:
    print("film")
    addfilm=Addfilms(request.POST,request.FILES, prefix='film')
    print(addfilm)
    if addfilm.is_valid():
        print("film")
        return redirect(view_accueil, inscription=3)

else :
    print("dfsd")
    addfilm=Addfilms(prefix='film')

if request.method == 'POST' and 'serie' in request.POST:
    print("serie")
    addserie=Addseries(request.POST,request.FILES, prefix='serie')
    if addserie.is_valid():
        print("serie")
        return redirect(view_accueil, inscription=3)
else : 
    addserie=Addseries(prefix='serie')


return render(request, 'menuAjout.html',locals())
```

my html :

```
<form action="{% url "add_files" %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ recherche.as_p }}
<input type="submit" id="validation" name="search"/>
</form>
<div id="films">
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %} 

<form action="{% url "add_files" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form addfilm %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbutton" name="film" value="submit">
      {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Ajouter
    </button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
</div>
<div id="series">
<form action="{% url "add_files" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form addserie %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbutton" name="serie">
      {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Ajouter
    </button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
</div>
```

my forms :

```
class Addseries(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = series
        exclude = ('nbTelechargement','datedepot')

class Addfilms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = series
        exclude = ('nbTelechargement','datedepot')

class searchbar(forms.Form):
    motclef=forms.CharField(max_length=15,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search...','style':'background :#ededef url("/static/image/search.png") no-repeat;background-size: auto 90%;'}))
    categorie=forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('films', 'films'),
                                                  ('séries', 'séries'),
                                                  ('jeux', 'jeux'),
                                                  ('logiciels', 'logiciels'),
                                                  ('livres', 'livres'),
                                                  ('musiques', 'musiques')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form balise.

My request.FILES was empty because of that.

So my form was unvalid because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I see several things:

1. It's not a Django issue but a HTML one:

When a user submits a form, he/she submits only form.
Django receives in `request.POST` only the data sent by one form.

2. Your forms share the same fields' names.

`Addseries.nbTelechargement` and `Addfilms.nbTelechargement` will have the same key in `request.POST`

Comment: When i say "all my informations", i mean my information about the form which I submited so it should be good (sorry i wasn't accurate)

Comment: I think that django make the difference thanks to the name of my submit button. here is my  POST request : <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['uKwr9zrkwpsjuKPQjo1fphCm7wcrnXJ3lYdX7qigWoFByGDu0hlFmZeWW7Vujrr5'], 'film-titre': ['775858785'], 'film-annee': ['587578578578'], 'film-Genre': ['78555775'], 'film-realisateur': ['5758558'], 'film-qualite': ['585557885'], 'film-langage': ['578758758578'], 'film-soustitre': ['8558857857'], 'film-photo': ['interface.jpg'], 'film-synopsis': ['8575578758878'], 'film-fichier': ['interface.jpg'], 'film': ['submit']}>  Obviously, these values are just a test.